# Multiple data frames - Wide to long using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two data frames like as shown below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11, 21, 31, 41, 51],
                        'date_1': ['12/30/1961', '05/29/1967', '02/03/1957', '7/27/1959', '01/13/1971'],
                        'date_2': ['07/23/2017','05/29/2017','02/03/2015',np.nan,np.nan]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11,21,31],
                    'visit_id':['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2'],
                    'date_start': ['01/01/2012', '02/25/2017', '02/03/2015', '07/27/2016', '01/13/2011'],
                    'date_end': ['05/03/2012','05/29/2017','03/03/2015','08/15/2016','02/13/2011']})
```

I tried the below. **I want only the date columns in a long format**

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='person_id',how='outer')
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['date'], i='person_id', j='grp').sort_index(level=0)
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
df
```

But this gives an empty data frame.

I would like to **get all the dates of each subject** as shown below (sample output for 2 subjects)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just `melt` and `concat`:

```
(pd.concat([df1.melt('person_id', value_name='dates'), 
            df2.melt('person_id',value_vars=['date_start','date_end'], value_name='dates')
          ])
   .drop('variable', axis=1)
   .sort_values('person_id')
)
```

Comment: When I type `reset_index` why do I see `index` column being created instead of renumbering the indices

Comment: I did this `(pd.concat([df1.melt('person_id', value_name='dates'), 
            df2.melt('person_id',value_vars=['date_start','date_end'], value_name='dates')
          ])
   .drop('variable', axis=1)
   .sort_values('person_id').reset_index()
)`

Comment: `reset_index(drop=True)` will not create `index` column.

Comment: Okay, so we should use `value_vars` parameter in `melt` function when we wish to specify column names. else it will consider all the columns. Am I right?

Comment: Can help with this please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432928/no-of-days-to-previous-and-next-year-pandas