# Shift dates by value unique for each subject

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11, 21, 31, 41, 51],
                        'date_1': ['12/30/1961', '05/29/1967', '02/03/1957', '7/27/1959', '01/13/1971'],
                        'date_2': ['07/23/2017','05/29/2017','02/03/2015',np.nan,np.nan]})
df1 = df1.melt('person_id', value_name='dates')
df1['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['dates'])
df1 = df1.assign(pd= (df1['dates'].dt.dayofyear - 1),
     nd=((df1['dates'] + pd.offsets.YearEnd(1)) - df1['dates']).dt.days)
```

With the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432928/no-of-days-to-previous-and-next-year-pandas), I am able to achieve part of what I wanted to.

Now what I would like to do is

a) Shift the dates backward (subtract) based on `minimum of pd value` for each subject
b) Shift the dates forward (add) based on  `minimum of nd value` for each subject
c) Check whether the `year` component remains the same between 3 columns `dates`, `shift_forward` and `shift_backward`

So, I got the `minimum of pd and nd values` using the code below

```
min_pd = df1.groupby(['person_id'])['pd'].min()
min_nd = df1.groupby(['person_id'])['nd'].min()
year_change = df1.dates.dt.year.eq(df1.shift_backward.dt.year(df1.shift_forward.dt.year))
```

but not sure how can I use this `min_pd` and `min_nd` as date offset for each subject.

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can first do a `transform` min with groupby and then your calculation would be easy with `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
#get groupby min transformed to the length of the dataframe
min_pd_nd = df1.groupby('person_id')['pd','nd'].transform('min')

df1['Shift_backward'] = df1['dates'].sub(pd.to_timedelta(min_pd_nd['pd'],unit='d'))
df1['Shift_Forward'] = df1['dates'].add(pd.to_timedelta(min_pd_nd['nd'],unit='d'))
#check if in a given row all year are unique 
c = (df1[['dates','Shift_backward','Shift_Forward']].stack(dropna=False).dt.year
     .groupby(level=0).nunique())
df1['year_change'] = np.where(c.gt(1),'Yes','No')
```

---

```
print(df1[['person_id','dates','Shift_backward','Shift_Forward','year_change']])

   person_id      dates Shift_backward Shift_Forward year_change
0         11 1961-12-30     1961-06-10    1961-12-31          No
1         21 1967-05-29     1967-01-01    1967-12-31          No
2         31 1957-02-03     1957-01-01    1957-12-31          No
3         41 1959-07-27     1959-01-01    1959-12-31          No
4         51 1971-01-13     1971-01-01    1971-12-31          No
5         11 2017-07-23     2017-01-01    2017-07-24          No
6         21 2017-05-29     2017-01-01    2017-12-31          No
7         31 2015-02-03     2015-01-01    2015-12-31          No
8         41        NaT            NaT           NaT          No
9         51        NaT            NaT           NaT          No
```

Comment: Hi @anky - One quick question. For the `min_pd_nd`, I am not able to get the `person_id` in the output of the group by statement.. I want to see the group by column in output (`min_pd_nd`] as well. I tried the below but it doesn't work. `df1['person_id'].groupby('person_id')['pd','nd'].transform('min')`

Comment: @TheGreat yes that doesnt return the group, but since it is index aligned we can take advantage of join `df[['person_id']].join(min_pd_nd)` :-)

Comment: In this line `df1['dates'].sub(pd.to_timedelta(min_pd_nd['pd'],unit='d'))`, how are we ensuring that we are subtracting the `min_pd` / `min_nd` for a subject with it's corresponding dates. Meaning another subject's `min_pd/min_nd` shouldn't be subtracted with other subjects

Comment: Once we get `min_pd` and `min_nd` for each subject, we use those values to subtract/add the dates for corresponding subjects.. Meaning subject_ids should match

Comment: @TheGreat because we are transforming the groupby min result across the original size dataframe so each index where people id is same will have same min_pd , so we can safely subtract -> pandas is index aligned, you can test it and let me know

Comment: actually I tried executing it on my end and encountering some issues..  Is there anyway to explicitly to provide the `subject_id` match?

Comment: @TheGreat yes , then merge your result of groupby().min() to the dataframe on people id and then subtract

Comment: can help me with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635778/exclude-a-specific-date-based-on-a-condition-using-pandas